# Various ways to set up alternative mathfrak fonts

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I am using TeXLive on Linux. I have installed the [esstix package](https://ctan.org/pkg/esstix?lang=en). After looking at `esstixfrak.sty` and `stix2.sty`,  I now know one way to use, in the same document, three different mathfrak fonts. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
% setting up mathfrak from stix2
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{STIX2symbols2}      {LS1}{stix2frak} {m} {n}
\SetSymbolFont{STIX2symbols2}    {bold}{LS1}{stix2frak} {b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\STIXTwoMathfrak}{STIX2symbols2}
% setting up mathfrak from esstix
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\EsstixMathFrak}{U}{esstixfrak}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{E}\STIXTwoMathfrak{E}\EsstixMathFrak{E}$
\end{document}
```

This produces the mathfrak "E" using the fonts, in order, `txmiaX`, `STIXTwoMath`, and `ESSTIX-Fifteen`.

Note the different manners in which `\STIXTwoMathfrak` and `\EsstixMathFrak` are defined.

Questions:

1. What are some advantages and disadvantages of these two ways of defining these alternative mathfrak commands?
2. Is it possible to define `\EsstixMathFrak` in a manner that is analogous to the way `\STIXTwoMathfrak` is defined, in particular, without declaring a new math alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classic tex only has 16 math families per math expression (luatex has more) symbol fonts have to be pre-allocated a number as a command  like `\Rightarrow` ultimately is defined via

```
\mathchardef\Rightarrow="3229
```

so font family 2 (the second hex digit) has to be the font encoded with an arrow in position hex 29.

Conversely if a command such as `\mathbb` is only used as `\mathbb{Q}` and never as a symbol `\mathchardef` latex can allocate these on demand  just if  they are used, so you can *declare* more than 16 math alphabets, but they do not get allocated if not used. `\DeclareMathAlphabet`

Sometimes, notably `\mathrm` in the standard setup, a font that has been pre-allocated for some symbols, also has a math alphabet in the letter slot, `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` sets up the math alphabet to re-use the existing allocation.

So if adding "extra" math alphabets not closely tied to your main math symbol setup, you should almost always use \DeclareMathAlphabet`rather than`\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`

in your example you declared two math alphabet, but the esstix one will not affect the 16 math font limit if you do not use it. As you allocate stix 2 via `\DeclareSymbolFont` it always takes up one of the 16 slots (or 2, if you load `bm` package)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some questions. First, if I understood you correctly, it would be better if `\STIXTwoMathfrak` were defined like `\EsstixMathFrak`. But if, in my MWE, I replace the code between `% setting up mathfrak from stix2` and `% setting up mathfrak from esstix` by `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\STIXTwoMathfrak}{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}`, I get the error `Encoding scheme LS1 is unknown`.

Comment: @linguisticturn keep `\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}`

Comment: Thank you! Why the corresponding commands aren't necessary for `\EsstixMathFrak`?

Comment: they are declared using `U` (unknown) encoding which is pre-declared. You could do that for stix2 as well if you only want the letters (which are in standard ascii slots) and will never want the custom math symbols which are laid out according to LS1 and LS2 encoding in the stix and stix2 packages